# Gtk.Application.run() versus Gtk.main() Last Chance Exception Handling in Python3

Tags: python-3.x, gtk3

I created a last chance exception handler for my test `Gtk.Application` but it is never hit.  However if I don't use `Gtk.Application` but use `Gtk.main()` to start my test app, the last chance exception handler is hit.

The sample below has 2 functions (`test_gtk_main()` and `test_gtk_application()`) which show what I mean.  Both functions deliberately cause a `NameError: name '_on_window_delete' is not defined`.  Both functions have a last chance exception handler.  Only the exception handler for `test_gtk_main()` is hit.

My question:  How can I modify `test_gtk_application` so the last chance exception handler is hit?

Sample code:

```
import logging

import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk, Gio

#set up logging
date_fmt = '%Y-%m-%d,%H:%M:%S'
log_format = '%(levelname)s %(asctime)s.%(msecs)03d %(name)s.%(funcName)s %(message)s'
logging.basicConfig(format=log_format, datefmt=date_fmt, level=logging.INFO)
_logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
_logger.info('Gtk version is %s.%s.%s', Gtk.MAJOR_VERSION, Gtk.MINOR_VERSION, Gtk.MICRO_VERSION)

def test_gtk_main():
    try:
        window = Gtk.Window(title="Window")
        window.connect("delete-event", _on_window_delete)
        window.show_all()
        Gtk.main()
    except Exception as ex:
        _logger.exception("\nLast Chance Exception Gtk.main() Caught '%s'", ex)

def test_gtk_application():
    try:
        app_id = "org.foo.example"
        flags = Gio.ApplicationFlags.FLAGS_NONE
        app = Gtk.Application.new(app_id, flags)
        app.connect("startup", do_startup, app)
        app.connect("activate", do_activate, app)
        app.connect("shutdown", do_shutdown, app)
        app.run()
    except Exception as ex: #never hit
        _logger.exception("\nLast Chance Exception Gtk.Application() Caught '%s'", ex)

def do_startup(self, app):
    _logger.debug("entered do_startup")

def do_activate(self, app):
    win = Gtk.ApplicationWindow(title="Test")
    win.connect("delete-event", _on_window_delete)

def do_shutdown(self, app):
    _logger.debug("entered do_shutdown")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    test_gtk_main()         #exception handler hit
    test_gtk_application()  #exception handler ignored
```

And here is the output (run from terminal on Ubuntu 18.04)

```
$ python3 test_gtk_exception_handler_3.py
INFO 2020-07-18,12:47:37.849 __main__.<module> Gtk version is 3.22.30
ERROR 2020-07-18,12:47:37.880 __main__.test_gtk_main 
Last Chance Exception Gtk.main() Caught 'name '_on_window_delete' is not defined'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_gtk_exception_handler_3.py", line 17, in test_gtk_main
    window.connect("delete-event", _on_window_delete)
NameError: name '_on_window_delete' is not defined

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_gtk_exception_handler_3.py", line 40, in do_activate
    win.connect("delete-event", _on_window_delete)
NameError: name '_on_window_delete' is not defined
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are trying to catch the exception in the wrong place.

the exception is function named "_on_window_delete" is not defined.
In test_gtk_main function, you are directly trying to connect to "_on_window_delete" that's why you are catching that error.

But in test_gtk_application you are adding "do_activate" as a callback function so the function "_on_window_delete" is not directly executed in the try statement. That's why you are not catching an error. but if you move the try clause to do_activate function it will work properly.

```
def do_activate(self, app):
    try:
        win = Gtk.ApplicationWindow(title="Test")
        win.connect("delete-event", _on_window_delete)
    except Exception as ex: #never hit
        _logger.exception("\nLast Chance Exception Gtk.Application() Caught '%s'", ex)
```

or if you move that exception code to the try clause in function "test_gtk_application"
that will also catch the exception

```
def test_gtk_application():
    try:
        app_id = "org.foo.example"
        flags = Gio.ApplicationFlags.FLAGS_NONE
        app = Gtk.Application.new(app_id, flags)
        win = Gtk.ApplicationWindow(title="Test")

        app.connect("startup", do_startup, app)
        app.connect("activate", do_activate, app)
        app.connect("shutdown", do_shutdown, app)
        win.connect("delete-event", _on_window_delete)
        app.run()
    except Exception as ex: #never hit
        _logger.exception("\nLast Chance Exception Gtk.Application() Caught '%s'", ex)
```

then you would get the exception as below

```
    INFO 2020-07-19,13:49:57.773 __main__.<module> Gtk version is 3.24.20
ERROR 2020-07-19,13:49:58.091 __main__.test_gtk_main 
Last Chance Exception Gtk.main() Caught 'name '_on_window_delete' is not defined'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "exception.py", line 17, in test_gtk_main
    window.connect("delete-event", _on_window_delete)
NameError: name '_on_window_delete' is not defined
ERROR 2020-07-19,13:49:58.092 __main__.test_gtk_application 
Last Chance Exception Gtk.Application() Caught 'name '_on_window_delete' is not defined'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "exception.py", line 33, in test_gtk_application
    win.connect("delete-event", _on_window_delete)
NameError: name '_on_window_delete' is not defined
```

basically, to catch an exception it has to run in the try clause, or else you won't be able to catch that error. for more details, I would suggest you look into (https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html)